# help me pick the right iPhone audio class - MPMoviePlayer vs AVAudioPlayer vs MPMusicPlayer

Tags: iphone, audio, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmusicplayercontroller

Does anyone know of a good tutorial on the distinction between the MPMoviePlayer vs AVAudioPlayer vs MPMusicPlayer?

I want to play audio from an mp3 file available at an external URL.

Ideally it is played in an iPod-like audio view.  I toyed with MPMoviePlayer but it appears to be more suitable for video, as when audio starts a "movie playing" message displays, the controls disappear and a white quicktime splash page displays.

I would like the standard ipod audio controls to display all the time, and to customize the image behind them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great little group of articles from Ray Wenderlich. Not specifically what you're after but might come in handy.

[Audio 101 for iPhone Developers: Playing Audio Programmatically](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/RayWenderlich/~3/2vErJJpxIJY/audio-101-for-iphone-developers-playing-audio-programmatically)

[Audio 101 for iPhone Developers: File and Data Formats](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/RayWenderlich/~3/Y3in1grjrWY/audio-101-for-iphone-developers-file-and-data-formats)

[Audio 101 for iPhone Developers: Converting and Recording](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/RayWenderlich/~3/-erNolmuKug/audio-101-for-iphone-developers-converting-and-recording)